# Pulling an appointment from a MySQL Database and displaying it's details in a MonthlyCalendar

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm having an issue I can't seem to solve. The basis of my program is basically setting reminders. I have a monthly calendar that shows dates in bold which I've saved in my MySql database. What I'm trying to do is allow the user to click on one of the bolded days and then it shows details about the appointment. As of right now, when there's an appointment it's in bold but when they click on the day that's bolded, none of the notes that I've saved with that date are showing.

```
Private Sub appt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        MonthCalendar1.MinDate = Date.Today 'SETS CALENDAR TO CURRENT DATE AND FUTURE ONLY

        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection 'ESTABLISHING CONNECTION
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=****;userid=****;password=****;database=****" 'DB INFO
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Dim eventDate As Date
            Query = "select datetext FROM database1.table8 ORDER BY datetext" 'SEARCHING FOR DATES IN MY DATABASE FOR MY CALENDAR TO DISPLAY IN BOLD
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            If READER.HasRows = True Then
                While READER.Read
                    eventDate = READER.GetValue(READER.GetOrdinal("datetext"))
                    MonthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(CDate(eventDate))'BOLDING DATES
                End While
                READER.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
                    Control.Text = String.Empty
                End If
            Next
            MySqlConn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
```

After learning how to display my dates in bold, I now want to be able to click on those dates and then have it open a new form displaying information associated with the appointment. Information associated with the appointment is stored in the MySQL database. **I'm not sure how to pull it from the database once I've clicked on the date.** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected

        TextBox1.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString() 'SENDS CALENDAR DATE TO TEXTBOX

        setappt.cddate.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString() SENDS CALENDAR DATE TO TEXTBOX IN A DIFFERENT FORM

        t = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Month.ToString & MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString



        m = MsgBox("Would you like to enter appointments for this date?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) 'WHEN YOU CLICK ON A DAY WITHOUT AN APPOINTMENT IT ASKS IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO CREATE AND APPOINTMENT
        If m = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            MonthCalendar1.Enabled = False
            MonthCalendar1.Hide()
            setappt.Enabled = True
            setappt.Show()
            'setdate.Text = ""
            PictureBox2.Enabled = True
            PictureBox2.Show()
            PictureBox3.Enabled = True
            PictureBox3.Show()
        Else

        End If

    End Sub
```

The first chunk of code is for searching out the bolded dates in my database. The second bit is for generating new appointments. I assume all I would need to do is "if bolded date is in the database, then the user can click on bolded date and retrieve the details"

Sorry for all the writing I'm just trying to provide all the necessities so I could get some help. Thanks!

Edit: **SOLVED** Thanks to @Abu6is for all the help! Code is below:

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected

'setappt.cddate.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString()



If (MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates.Contains(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart)) Then

TextBox1.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString

MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection

MySqlConn.ConnectionString =

"server=****;userid=****;password=****;database=****"

Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

Try

MySqlConn.Open()

Dim Query As String

Query = "select * FROM database1.table8 WHERE datetext = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)

READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

While READER.Read

TextBox2.Text = READER.GetString("casename")

TextBox1.Text = READER.GetString("datetext")

TextBox3.Text = READER.GetString("type")



End While



Catch ex As Exception

MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

Finally

MySqlConn.Dispose()

End Try

Else

TextBox1.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToShortDateString

m = MsgBox("Would you like to enter appointments for this date?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

If m = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

MonthCalendar1.Enabled = False

MonthCalendar1.Hide()

setappt.Enabled = True

setappt.Show()

'setdate.Text = ""

PictureBox2.Enabled = True

PictureBox2.Show()

PictureBox3.Enabled = True

PictureBox3.Show()

Else



End If

End If



End Sub
```

Comment: You simply need to select the note info from your database where the datetext in you db is equal to the selected date.

Comment: @Anu6is Added some new code to my initial post. Not sure if that's the correct way to be doing it but I think I'm getting somewhere. Some insight would be great if you can!

Comment: Looks OK so far. Ideally you would only want this to run when the selected date is bold. It's fine if it runs for any date selected but it's essentially a wasted db call if you know there is no data to return.

Comment: @Anu6is Thanks for your reply! The problem I'm now having is creating the if statement for it. It's throwing me an error when I try to describe if the dateselected is bolded. It doesn't allow a boolean for a date. I hate to keep prying but do you know any way around this? Thanks! Edit: I've found some csharp code that I'm going to give a try at:  if (monthCalendar1.BoldedDates.Contains(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart))

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: The code I edited my post with is what I'm going to roll with once I get my if statement together for the bold. What I have so far is something along the lines of this: If MonthCalendar1.BoldedDates.Contains

Comment: I don't know what those variables are thought. BoldedDates is a list of what? also what is selection start? I don't see why `if (monthCalendar1.BoldedDates.Contains(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart))` won't work

Comment: You're exactly right. I just realized that and changed it. I've just edited the initial post with thew new if statement I'm running with. For some reason, it's bypassing the bolded section completely and automatically trying to add a new appointment. Edit: SelectionEnd only seems to work for me I don't know why SelectionStart isn't wanting to display the dateselected in a textbox.

Comment: You should debug an inspect the variable to see if they contain what u think they do.

Comment: Good idea. For some reason, when I try to transfer one of the bolded dates to a textbox, it doesn't work. For non-bolded dates, it seems to work out fine. I'm encountering new problems from my old problems lol but such is the life of a programmer.